# CodeIgniter Append URI Segment With Relative Link

Tags: javascript, php, html, apache, codeigniter

I have pagination links at the bottom of the page. When I click the link I would need the URL like so:

```
http://localhost/controller/function/products/1     // <-- page number
```

But the relative link replaces the query strings after the function name:

```
http://localhost/controller/function/1
```

How can I append the page number together with the query string `/products/`?

**NOTE:** I need relative links so they work with any number of query strings before the page number by appending the page number last.

**My Code:**

```
echo "<li><a href='$page_num'>$page_num</a></li>";
```

Comment: Can we see more code?

Comment: @AliGajani The rest of the code is just the construction of the pagination data which is just a loop through a number array... Simply put, you click the link and everything after the function name is replaced with the page number.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep the link relative, you can use the following code:

`echo "<li><a href='products/$page_num'>$page_num</a></li>";`

Comment: The problem is that I have many formats for the url such as regular query strings (`?var=val`) and URI segments with CodeIgniter that vary in segments so `products` might not always have products and instead will be categories, for example. I could create a `switch` statement or maybe `if/else` for each case I just think there should be a better solution.

Comment: So are you saying that, more generically, the link needs to point to `$relative_path/$page_num?$query_string` ?  It might help if you could post some more example URLs that you need to link to.

Comment: The link should ALWAYS append the page number at the end. Now, the URLS vary, for example I might have: `http://localhost/controller/function/products/1` or `http://localhost/controller/function/products/listings/1`. So it would help if the page number was always last without replacing previous URI segments.